# Traverse to a specific string in a python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml

Below is the content of a YAML file. I want to write a python code in order to traverse to a specific case name and then change the value of enabled from true to false. For example: Traversing to login case name and then changing enabled value to false. how can I do that ?

```
tiers:
-
    name: testing
    order: 1
    description: ''
    testcases:
        -
            case_name: console_access
            project_name: project
            enabled: true
            criteria: 100
            blocking: false
            clean_flag: false
            description: ''
            run:
                name: 'console_access'

        -
            case_name: login
            project_name: project
            enabled: true
            criteria: 100
            blocking: false
            clean_flag: false
            description: ''
            run:
                name: 'login'

        -
            case_name: project_creation
            project_name: project
            enabled: true
            criteria: 100
            blocking: false
            clean_flag: false
            description: ''
            run:
                name: 'project_creation'

        -
            case_name: network_creation
            project_name: project
            enabled: true
            criteria: 100
            blocking: false
            clean_flag: false
            description: ''
            run:
                name: 'network_creation'
```

Comment: try to use [pyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/#:~:text=YAML%20is%20a%20data%20serialization,API%2C%20and%20sensible%20error%20messages.)

Comment: @leminhnguyenHUST hey.. could you please brief me on how to write a python code ?

Comment: @Oshinaggrawal There doesn't appear to be a `horizon_login' case_name in the data you've posted.

Comment: @norie  hey sry.. that's case name : login

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
import yaml

y = yaml.safe_load(open("data.yaml", "r")) 

for i in y["tiers"]:
    for j in i["testcases"]:
        if j["case_name"] == "login":
            j["enabled"] = False

yaml.dump(y, open("new_data.yaml", "x"))
```

Comment: Is it possible to give more than one case_name ?

Answer (score 1):

As has been suggested you could use [PyYAML](https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/#:%7E:text=YAML%20is%20a%20data%20serialization,API%2C%20and%20sensible%20error%20messages.).

Now let's say you have the YAML in a file named `cases.yaml`.

You could then use this code to read the data in and make the required change.

Note this code writes to a new file named `new_cases.yaml` but that can easily be changed to write back to the original file.

```py
import yaml

with open('cases.yaml') as file:
    case_list = yaml.load(file, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
    for case in case_list['tiers'][0]['testcases']:
      if case['case_name'] == 'login':
        case['enabled'] = False

with open('new_case.yaml', 'w') as file:
    documents = yaml.dump(case_list, file)
```

Comment: Is it possible to give more than one case_name ?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: At this step :   if case['case_name'] == 'login':
Can I mention one or more case_name
@norie

Comment: Hey @norie .. could you plz answer the above ques ?

Comment: Do you have a list of case names you want to find?

Comment: Thanks for replying. Actually I have set a condition that if a platform is not deployed then the cases names mentioned in above YAML file should skip. And skipping is only possible if for each casename the respective value of enabled is set to false.

Comment: With the help of your code, I am able to change value for enable just for the one casename which I mention not for all. Is there any work around, I could skip all casenames.