# Pyyaml conditional statement

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

In the below code, I need to give more than one case name.
For example: Giving "login" and "deploy" casenames
**if j["case_name"] == "login" and "deploy"**
And then change enabled value for both to **False** Is it possible ? or there is some other way where I can change enabled value to false for more than one casename.

```
    import yaml

y = yaml.safe_load(open("data.yaml", "r")) 

for i in y["tiers"]:
    for j in i["testcases"]:
        if j["case_name"] == "login":
            j["enabled"] = False

yaml.dump(y, open("new_data.yaml", "x"))





Below  is the content from YAML file
    tiers:
    -
        name: testing
        order: 1
        description: ''
        testcases:
            -
                case_name: deploy
                project_name: project
                enabled: true
                criteria: 100
                blocking: false
                clean_flag: false
                description: ''
                run:
                    name: 'deploy'
    
            -
                case_name: login
                project_name: project
                enabled: true
                criteria: 100
                blocking: false
                clean_flag: false
                description: ''
                run:
                    name: 'login'
```

Comment: how can one string be equal to two different strings. Wont that always be false?

Comment: @BuddyBob 
if j["case_name"] == "login" and if j["case_name"] == "deploy":
Is the above statement wrong ? can't we add something like that. I have added YAML FILE content above for reference.

Comment: @BuddyBob Or some other work around ?

Comment: I did not see the file in your original post, so I had no idea of the format. Thank you for posting that.

Comment: @BuddyBob Here is the link which will provide you some idea regarding the same
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67720784/traverse-to-a-specific-string-in-a-python-code/67721257?noredirect=1#comment119731373_67721257

Comment: @Oshinaggrawal Logic dictates that at most one of the conditions `x == "login"` and `x == "deploy"` can be true. This means that `x == "login" and x == "deploy"` will be false for any given *x*.

Comment: @flyx How to make value false for both x ?? Any work around ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not completely sure this is what you want but it sounds like you want to do

```py
for i in y["tiers"]:
    for j in i["testcases"]:
        if j["case_name"] in ["login", "deploy"]:
            j["enabled"] = False
```

I advise to describe what you want to do in prose instead of giving misleading pseudocode since a logical *and* does not make any sense in this case – you most likely want a logical *or*, which is what this code implements.